# Transpose within Transpose Notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++

I have a text file that looks like this (but 132k lines)

```
********
name : one
Place : city
Initial: none
********
name : two
Place : city2
Initial: none
********
name : three
Place : city3
Initial: none
Limits : some
```

I'm trying to move it into a more friendly format (excel/database records). Each 'record' is separated by the ********, the fields for 90% of the records are all the same, but some have additional fields, like the limits in the 3rd record.

I would like a csv, or similar output like:

```
name,place,initial,limit
one,city,none,n/a
two,city2,none,n/a
three,city3,none,some
```

Is python better suited for parsing and manipulating this?

Comment: Yes, this would be a very simple Python program.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Notepad++ regex replace of `([^*\r\n])\R([^*\r\n])` with `\1,\2` will change the input example text to be:

```
********
name : one,Place : city,Initial: none
********
name : two,Place : city2,Initial: none
********
name : three,Place : city3,Initial: none,Limits : some
```

This can be followed by marking (use menu => **Search** => **Mark...**) with a regex of `^\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*$` and finally removing the marked lines (use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove Bookmarked Lines**).

You may need to tidy up the very start and end of the text, including adding the line of column titles.

**Variations:**

Whitespace at the start or end of lines may lead to unwanted changes, so it might be best to remove it before replacing line-breaks with commas. Use menu => **Edit** => **Blank Operations** => **Trim Leading and Trailing Space**.

The Number of asterisks may be different on some lines. So perhaps change the marking regex to be `^\*\*\*\*\*\*\**$`. Adjust the number of `\*` to match the minimum in the source text.

**The Regular Expressions**

```
(                 Start of capture group 1
  [^*\r\n]        A negated character class: Not the characters *, CR and LF
                  This captures the last character on the line
)                 End of capture group
\R                A line break
(                 Start of capture group 2
  [^*\r\n]        As above, captures the first character on the line
)
```

The replacement is `\1,\2`, meaning insert the two captured characters separated by a comma.

The marking regex of `^\*\*\*\*\*\*\*$` means start of line `^` then several `\*` meaning actual asterisks finally the `$` means end-of-line. The variation of `^\*\*\*\*\*\*\**$` adds a `*` near the end, meaning zero-or-more occurrences of the last actual asterisk.

Comment: Wow thank you! I can't even begin to understand this, but I'll test it on Monday